# Validation cleared out at the end of function in javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation

I have created function for validation textboxes in ASP.NET web forms. Validation should happen in a modal pop up. But it does not show messages when the fields are empty.
When I have put an alert at the end of the function to check if it enters the function, it showed validations properly.

Here is simple function for Validation that should close pop up if everything is good or show error messages if something went wrong.

```
function validateAndCloseDirectDebitDialog(validationGroup, dialogID) {
       var pageValid = Page_ClientValidate(validationGroup);
       if (pageValid)
       $(dialogID).modal("hide");

}
```

And if I simply add alert like this:

```
function validateAndCloseDirectDebitDialog(validationGroup, dialogID) {
       var pageValid = Page_ClientValidate(validationGroup);
       if (pageValid)
       $(dialogID).modal("hide");
       alert("Hello from Validation!");           
}
```

It shows proper validation message.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting validationGroup with RequiredFieldValidator like this

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="reqInvestgator" ControlToValidate="txtRevisionName"  
       ErrorMessage="Enter Revision Name" ValidationGroup="CreateRevisionGroup"> <font face="Verdana" size="1">* </font>
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Then you should use it in `Page_ClientValidate` function.

```
 if (Page_ClientValidate('CreateRevisionGroup')) {
       //Your page is valid go ahead.
 }
 else {
        alert("Validation Failed..Enter required data");
        return false;
 }
```